Is the Postgres documentation's Emacs code for using a Postgres mode bugged?
The Postgres documentation contains this code
;; check for files with a path containing "postgres" or "pgsql"
(setq auto-mode-alist
  (cons '("\\(postgres\\|pgsql\\).*\\.[ch]\\'" . pgsql-c-mode)
        auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist
  (cons '("\\(postgres\\|pgsql\\).*\\.cc\\'" . pgsql-c-mode)
        auto-mode-alist))

(defun pgsql-c-mode ()
  ;; sets up formatting for PostgreSQL C code
  (interactive)
  (c-mode)
  (setq-default tab-width 4)
  (c-set-style "bsd")             ; set c-basic-offset to 4, plus other stuff
  (c-set-offset 'case-label '+)   ; tweak case indent to match PG custom
  (setq indent-tabs-mode t))      ; make sure we keep tabs when indenting

Even under emacs -Q, I cannot get this code to work as described. My file pgsql.pgsql does not open in pgsql-c-mode and adding "(postgres)" to its parent folder's name did not help.
Am I misunderstanding this code or does it simply not work?

Just FYI: your link points to the docs for version 8.1. The current version is 17, so you may want a more up-to-date version of PostgreSQL (and its documentation).

Also, that section is in a chapter under the part entitled Internals. If you are not a contributor to PostgreSQL at the coding level, you do not need to worry about that part/chapter/section.

What sort of file is your pgsql.pgsql?  (I.e. what kind of content does it contain?)

Regarding NickD's first comment, the up-to-date link for working with the Postgres source code in Emacs appears to be https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/tools/editors/emacs.samples;hb=HEAD along with their .dir-locals.el file https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob_plain;f=.dir-locals.el;hb=HEAD


Am I misunderstanding this code or does it simply not work?

Yes.
It is used for C/C++ files.  E.g., pgsql-test.cc; 
not

My file pgsql.pgsql

The mode name pgsql-c-mode also indicates that.

So why is there a ;; check for files with a path containing "postgres" or "pgsql" comment?

I imagine it's expecting the C code for the postgres to live under some sub-directory with "postgres" and/or "pgsql" in the directory name.  Possibly the source code releases contain directory structures which would guarantee this was the case.  E.g. /path/to/postgres-14/src/select.c (I am making up a file name here).

For clarity, the code they show (which could be simplified to a single regexp instead of two) is matching file paths which contain either of postgres pgsql somewhere, and which end with one of .c or .h or .cc.  (And my impression is that pgsql-c-mode is not going to be relevant to any other kind of file.)
